# Is it possible to add class members to base class A from derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I was just thinking about it and wondering if it's totally possible, just out of curiosity, as it would be very usefull I think. (but most of my ideas are crazy/insane anyway).

So here it goes:

Is it possible to create a class A, and class B, then add a member to class A by using class B?

Let's suppose we are making a game, or some program in which this would be usefull:

```
class Player
{
    public:
    float health;
};
```

Now, you think of a way to allow extensions by using include files or something:

```
#define INCLUDE_SPEEDO_METER
#ifdef INCLUDE_SPEEDO_METER
class PlayerSpeedo : public Player
{
    public:
    float absolute_speed;
    //Do some Magic here & there
};
#endif
```

Now let's suppose we want to access the absolute speed of a player from the `Player` class like `Player.absolute_speed`.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: No. You'd have to cast the `Player*` to a `PlayerSpeedo*`, and they'd have to be allocated on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: This is almost as bad as when a colleague suggested runtime disinheritence.... :)

Comment: @Cyber You don't need to allocate on the heap to downcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't syntactically do what you are hoping to do, you can achieve something very close by storing a `map` in the base class.

```
class Player
{
    public:

       Player(float health = 0) { data["health"] = health; }

       float health() const { return get("health"); }
       float get(std::string const& field) const { return data[field]; }

    protected:
       std::map<std::string, float> data;
};

class PlayerSpeedo : public Player
{
    public:

       PlayerSpeedo(float absolute_speed) {data["absolute_speed" = absolute_speed; }
       float absolute_speed() const { return get("absolute_speed"); }
};
```

Comment: that's actually a nice alternative! :)

Comment: OMG That will be such a slow program.

Comment: @jmucchiello, you've got a point. I hope the OP, or any body for that matter, won't do that in a performance critical section of the code.

Comment: And wait until he discovers he wants non-float properties.

Comment: Honestly, using a dynamic language might actually give better performance since compilers can optimize for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. You can't "inject" members into another class. Frankly, I can't see why you would ever want to. No one else than you would be aware of this "injected" member.

Comment: yeah that's the only obstacle I see to which I couldn't come up with a solution :P As for why anyonewould do that, well some time ago (read: years) I was thinking about a "dynamic extension" system for a game I made and was wondering if it's possible to modify members dynamically without ifdefs' :)

Comment: What you would typically do is to use a map that maps players to objects containing the auxiliary values. But I see where you're coming from, and I understand better why you asked the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is not possible in a statically typed language, but it would work in a dynamically typed language (like Python).

A way of achieving that in C++ would be to use a Map between string names of properties and some generic wrapper for property values.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're asking for, but would give you somewhat similar capabilities is the recent proposal for a future version of the C++ standard [Call syntax: x.f(y) vs. f(x,y)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf)

This would enable you to write a standalone function `float absolute_speed(const Player& p) { return 0.0f; }` that you could call via `Player p; auto speed = p.absolute_speed()` without changing the definition of Player. This is a similar idea to extension methods in C#.

Comment: Skimmed. A very good documment in my opinion, can't wait until it will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like the way which is often done to extend a base class by another class with a template like the following. There is no need for runtime polymorphism which is often a criteria for speed while optimizing can go down to the executed functions without stopping at the virtual functions.

As you can see from the example, it looks like injection of methods and attributes. C++11 offer it to use the constructor from the class which you use to extend the given class very simple. OK, this is a stupied example but maybe it give you an idea how the thing works.

```
#include <iostream>

class Empty
{
    public:

        void DoSomething() { std::cout << "Nothing" << std::endl;}
};

class Extender
{
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        Extender(int _x):x(_x) {}
        void DoSomething() { std::cout << "Value " << x << std::endl; }
};

template <typename ExtendWith>
class User: public ExtendWith
{
    public:
        using ExtendWith::ExtendWith;

        void DoIt() { ExtendWith::DoSomething(); }
};

int main()
{
    User<Empty> userEmpty;
    userEmpty.DoIt();

    User<Extender> userExtended(100);
    userExtended.DoIt();
}
```

Comment: It's very nice but not really doable with multiple extenders.. right?

Comment: It is also possible to use it with a variadic template which accepts as many as extenders you want. Simply unroll the template parameter list and make it `use` your extensions well. Thats because overwriting a method in a higher class will hide the lower ones. You can also derive from a complete parameter list but this results in some difficulties with the constructors if needed. If no parameters needed for construction you can simply do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the language could allow what you're trying to do without introducing inconsistencies.

I don't think you want to modify the actual type though, since what you describe is essentially converting a super-type instance into a sub-type instance.  You could do this by adding a constructor to the sub-type...

```
class PlayerSpeedo : public Player {

  public:

  float absolute_speed;

  explcit PlayerSpeedo(const Player& p, float absolute_speed=0, ...) : health(p.health) {

    // copy Player values

  }
```

Another option might be storing a reference to the original object, and [decorating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) it.  This doesn't alter the type though.